# Android get child from FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

If I create two classes, a Parent class which extends `FrameLayout`, and a Child class that extends `View`, and then use `XML` to initialise them. Is it possible to get child elements from the Parent class constructor? If i use `getChildAt()` , I always get null, since the activity is still not created.

```
 <com.example.Parent 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <com.example.Child
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.example.Child
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.example.Parent>
```

Parent and Child classes

```
public class Parent extends FrameLayout { 
    public Parent(@NonNull Context context) {
         super(context);
         this.getChildAt(0); // return null
    }
...  
}

public class Child extends View {  
...  
}
```

Comment: You can not get child in constructor `View` is not drawn yet . Whats your use case of getting child views? Edit your question with requirement so that someone can help .

Comment: you can take a look at `onFinishInflate` function.

Comment: onFinishInflate() will do the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling `getChildAt` at the construction of your `FrameLayout` you are getting null values (your children are still not fully attached to the view). One solution would be to overwrite `onLayout()` or `onMeasure()` to get your childs.

Answer (score 1):

Before inflating you can not get child view form Parent.

But you can do it dynamically but is also work in same way like , you have to add views manually to Parent view.

And then you can get child views form Parent View.